# How to get wifi ath10k/QCA6174 running on pureOS?

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, firmware

I installed pureOS, but couldn't get my Qualcomm wifi (ath10k/QCA6174) working. I found out that there are ways to make it work on other distros. However, Purism states that some Qualcomm wifi chips won't work, because they need proprietary firmware. 
Is the ath10k firmware not free? If it is, how can I make it work on pureOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PureOS is perfectly capable of using proprietary driver blobs, it's just a Debian fork. While it's not quite in the spirit of the OS, you can certainly follow instructions others have used to make `ath10k` drivers available to the OS. I'm typing this on a Yoga 910 with a QCA6174 WiFi chipset running PureOS and it works just fine.

You just need to first install PureOS without an internet connection.

Then, on an internet connected PC, download the firmware package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-atheros) or use `wget`:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-atheros_20161130-3_all.deb
```

Then just install the firmware package on your PureOS system and reboot.

```
sudo dpkg -i firmware-atheros_20161130-3_all.deb
reboot
```

Comment: i believe theres also a non-free repository as mentioned here: https://puri.sm/posts/purism-patches-meltdown-and-spectre-variant-2-both-included-in-all-new-librem-laptops/ `deb http://deb.puri.sm/pureos/ green contrib non-free` gpg key available at: https://deb.puri.sm/pureos/key/purism-nonfre-repo.gpg.key

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the required firmware for the WiFi is proprietary therefore it can't be used in PureOS, which is an entirely open-source distro, without turning the OS into something it wasn't designed to be.